# Boolean Algebra expression with nots

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

So at the end of my truth table I got:

```
NOT  NOT ABC.NOT ABD

________
___ ___
ABC.ABD
```

Does this simplify into ABC+ABD? Also what laws would I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start I don't like the way they teach binary simplification. To make things much easier for yourself take these rules instead of the ones they taught you:

1. A AND B = AB
2. A AND A = A
3. A OR B = A + B - AB
4. NOT A = 1 - A

You can work out xor and etc.. yourself using these.

Now then using these rules:

```
NOT(NOT(A AND B AND C) AND (NOT (A AND B AND D)))

= 1 - ((1 - ABC)*(1 - ABD))

= 1 - (1 - ABC)(1 - ABD)

= 1 - 1 + ABD + ABC - ABCABD

= ABD + ABC - ABCD

= AB(D + C - CD)

= A AND B AND (C OR D)
```

which is equivalant to ABC + ABD using your system.

Edit:
First 3 equals (but a bit slower):

```
NOT(NOT(A AND B AND C) AND (NOT (A AND B AND D)))
->
NOT((NOT(ABC)) AND (NOT (ABD)))
->
1 - ((NOT(ABC))(NOT(ABD)))
->
1 - (1 - ABC)(1 - ABC)
-> expanding the brackets
1 - (1 * 1 - ABC * 1 - ABD * 1 + ABC * ABD)
->
1 - (1 - ABC - ABD + ABCABD)
-> multiple out the bracket
1 - 1 + ABD + ABC - ABCABD
```

glad I could help ^^

Comment: Thanks for the help + rules makes sense. Could you just explain the first 3 ='s a little more? Sorry this is very new to me and tyvm for the rules.